# Steps to configure SOAP webservice Provider in Hybris 2011?

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-framework-beans

Can someone help with the steps for configuring SOAP web service **provider** in **Hybris**. Given one WSDL as input to start. We have received a requirement wherein the business user wants to expose a SOAP web service API.

I am not getting any concrete solution how to do in hybris 2011.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.